# Using twix and momentjs in meteor

Tags: plugins, meteor, momentjs, meteorite

I'm trying to put together a small app using meteor, and having a lot of luck. But I can't get the app to use the [Twix](http://icambron.github.io/twix.js/) plugin for [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/).

Using Meteorite, I added the Momentjs library from Atmosphere, `mrt add moment`, so no problem there. But there's no twix package in Atmosphere. I used npm to install twix package, but neither meteor no mrt will `add` twix, responding `Package named twix doesn't exist in your meteor installation` which I guess makes sense, it being a Nodejs package not a Meteor package. Finally I tried downloading the twix.js file and placing it in different directories, but nothing has worked.

I'm not getting errors with this code:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        var moment = Npm.require('moment');
        Npm.require('twix');
    });
```

and I can use the MomentJS library, but not the twix plugin. Writing (within Meteor.isClient)

```
Template.dayTable.date = function() {
    return moment(Session.get('selectedDate')).format("MMM Do YY");
}
```

works fine, but writing

```
var t = new moment("1/25/1982 9:30 AM").twix("1/25/1982 1:30 PM");
```

has the js console tell me `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'twix'`

Is there a secret place I can put the twix.js file for Meteor/MomentJS to use (which seems likely)? Am I not require-ing it correctly? Or what?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor loads javascript in a certain order. See the [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/) (search for "load order"). To fix this:

- add moment.js to client/lib to ensure it's loaded before twix
- add twix.js to the client folder

You can also look into creating a package (which is what `Npm.require` is intended for) and include that, or rename the files since files are included alphabetically. More info is in the docs.

Comment: I was hoping to not deal with a directory structure, but using the 'parties' example, I put together a directory structure and placed the files as you suggested. Works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not documented anywhere, but you can also use Twix standalone, like this:

```
var Twix = Npm.require('twix');
var t = new Twix(firstTime, secondTime);
```